# SQL database to android SQLite database

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, development-environment

I've a table named `student`. I need to display attendance details of student by passing `Student_ID`. Database uses normal `MySQL` database on server-side to maintain the attendance register.

How to connect that `MySQL Server` to `Android` Application ?

Comment: check this easy and awesome tutorial..http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: Meghana Mathur A also check this..http://champakonline.blogspot.in/2011/12/basic-android-database-example.html

Comment: read this tutorial may be help you http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) but you do need a web-server for it.

Request mechanism
Android App ----> webserver  ------> database (mysql)

Respond mechanism
Android App <---- webserver  <------ database (mysql)

Android App will use [JSON](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) or [other](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html) to get the data and display it

Comment: yes please.... but do have to get something else installed in the mobile to run the JSON code run for the app???

Comment: no no JSON mainly convert response from the web-page (webserver) to ArrayList , HashMap.